# Modificar url si no existe php

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Estoy manejando las url con .htaccess y, de manera interna, estoy validando la URL.

Por ejemplo, cuando la URL a la que se accede es la siguiente:

```
home.dev/control/principal/index
```

Se reescribe a donde se encuentra el archivo con la siguiente estructura:

```
home.dev/aplicacion/carpeta/archivo
```

Esa es la manera correcta, y cuando escriben mal por ejemplo así:

```
    home.dev/control/principale/indexar
```

de manera interna lo valido y como no existe lo redirige a principal. Pero la URL queda como se escribió.

¿Existe alguna manera para cuando se escriba mal aparte de realizar la redirección cambie la URL?

Comment: quieres que resuelva solo una ruta?, puedes reescribir la ruta y obligarlo que siempre se vea por alli,  o por el contrario colocar en el vistualhost que vea la carpeta home.dev/aplicacion/carpeta/ y resuelva  home.dev/control/

Comment: Hola estimado, si osea de manera interna resuelvo el url es decir si la ruta no existe siempre se dirige al home, pero visualmente la url queda con la url incorrecta por decirlo de alguna manera

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente estás **reescribiendo** una dirección. La idea es que además **redirecciones**
(con el flag [`[R]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r)).

```python
RewriteEngine On

# Reescribir (internamente)
# control/principal/cualquier-archivo
#  ->  aplicacion/carpeta/cualquier-archivo
RewriteRule ^control/principal(?:/(.*))?$ aplicacion/carpeta/$1 [NC,L]

# Redireccionar (cambia la URL) 
# cuando no existe el directorio (-d) 
# ni el archivo (-f)
# al home
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ control/principal/index.php [NC,R,L]
```

Alternativamente, podrías hacer que cuando no encuentre el archivo, el error 404 sea tu propio home, usando la directiva [ErrorDocument](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html). De esa forma, el cliente se entera de que la dirección no existe, pero aún así ve la página principal. -Es diferente de lo que pediste, pero yo lo haría así.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /aplicacion/carpeta/index.php
```

Comment: Gracias estimado! de seguro funciona pero lo probare y comentare para que otro colega pueda ocuparlo también! saludos